# I am getting me.store.loading is undefined when I trigger fields using on load event on second load of the window

Tags: extjs

enter code hereI have a window in which I have a form with trigger fields. So by trigerring I mean , if I select a value from first combo, its trigerring the succeding combos with their's first values. This is working fine when I open the window for the first time. But if close it and open it for the second time, it will generate error as me.store.loading is undefined.

I am using on load event of combo to fire the next combo with its first value. Please see code below which I have put in the render event of a field in that window.

Thanks,
sj

```
me.control({
'addinp #renderCmp':{
                    render:me.registerTriggerCalls
                  }
})

registerTriggerCalls : function() {

var stcombo = Ext.getCmp('StField');
    stcombo.store.on('load', function(store, record, opts)
    {debugger;
        if (store.totalCount <= 0)
        { return; }

        stcombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).data.stThru);
        stcombo.fireEvent('select', stcombo);
    });



    var adcombo = Ext.getCmp('AdField');
    adcombo.store.on('load', function(store, record, opts)
    {
        if (store.totalCount <= 0)
        { return; }

        adcombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).data.adDate);
        adcombo.fireEvent('select', adcombo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the lifecycle of these objects? Are the form/combos getting destroyed and recreated each time?  When does the store get created?  I think your problem is likely that you have "dangling" event listeners on the store from previously destroyed combos, but not enough details to know for sure.

Comment: hi Joe, If I am right, the form and its components gettting destroyed by the close event. I am using EXT 4.2, so it could destroy by default. I am adding more code details above...

Comment: now I tried closeAction:'destroy' in my window, but still it shows me.store is null when we trigger combo while opening window for the second time....any ideas

Comment: do I need to destroy controller page as the event listeners are created on that page only....right now when we close window, only the view page is destroyed....can u please help me out?

Comment: One way to troubleshoot the problem I'm thinking of before I take you too far down the wrong path is to `console.log` the itemId on the combo box when it's created and again right before the exception is thrown (assuming you're using the auto-generated itemId).

Comment: That would tell you if the exception is happening on a listener that's still attached to the previous instance of the combo box

Comment: Hi Joe, I did a a fix now. I used the below code to remove listeners from the combo store. Ext.getCmp('StCombo').getStore().clearListeners();                   Ext.getCmp('AdCombo').getStore().clearListeners();                     Now I am able to close and open the window again and again without any errors...Is this approach is good or bad? I am using the above code at the beforeclose event of the window. thanks.

Comment: See my answer below. It's probably cleaner to use 'managed listeners' in this scenario. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When does the store get created/destroyed?  Are you creating a new store with each combo box or are you reusing a global store each time?

In the comments above, I give you a way to troubleshoot, but if you're reusing the same store object over and over, you either need to use a [managed listener](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-mon) (preferred) or unregister your handlers when your combo boxes are destroyed.

```
var stcombo = Ext.getCmp('StField');
stcombo.mon(store, 'load', function(store, record, opts)
{
    if (store.totalCount <= 0)
    { return; }

    stcombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).data.stThru);
    stcombo.fireEvent('select', stcombo);
});

var adcombo = Ext.getCmp('AdField');
adcombo.mon(store, 'load', function(store, record, opts)
{
    if (store.totalCount <= 0)
    { return; }

    adcombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).data.adDate);
    adcombo.fireEvent('select', adcombo);
});
```

Assuming that's the case, what's happening is that the life span of your store and your combo box is disconnected.  The listeners are tied to the store's life span which doesn't have visibility to the combo box's life span. Hence, the old listeners don't get removed until the store is destroyed which is obviously bad -- for a number of reasons -- but causing your exception because the closure references a destroyed combo box.

A managed listener solves this by essentially tying the listener's life span to the combo box instead of the store.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply....I am using standard store files under store folder, yes I am following MVC style. So in my page according to user selection of a particular data, I am triggering the calls using the registered listeners above....by the way how I use a  managed lsitener as you suggested above...any examples or links..which willl be a great help.

Comment: The sample code in my answer is how you do it.  Notice that I'm calling `stcombo.mon(store, ...)` as opposed to `stcombo.store.on(...)`.  That tells it to listen to the store, but remove the listener when the combo is destroyed.  `mon` is just a shortcut for `addManagedListener` just as `on` is a shortcut for `addListener`.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Joe, the above solution is working for me...also feeling I learnt something today.

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Also glad to know that I finally know enough about ExtJS now that I can start answering questions like these.

Comment: oh ok, then I will be disturbing you with my questions :)